# Android Google Map - display line above markers

Tags: android, google-maps

According to the Polyline documentation;

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

polylines can have a z-index that affects their height relative to other shapes, but not markers.  Markers are displayed at a higher level than all shapes.  So to get a line to display above the markers on the map, would I have to ditch Polyline entirely, and put a Canvas on a FrameLayout and handle the drawing of the line myself?  Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I dont think you can display a `polyline` above any `marker` even thought u set the `zIndex` to a big number. I think you can use the [fromScreenLocation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection#fromScreenLocation(android.graphics.Point)) method to convert your marker's position into a screen location, then you can draw a line between two different locations in your device screen.

Comment: Is that basically what I came up with as a fallback position?  Put another transparent view on top of the map, and draw on that myself?  That might complicate things since I need to figure out what markers the line is passing near, but I can figure that part out.

Comment: Yes, the [fromScreenLocation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection#fromScreenLocation(android.graphics.Point)) can help you translate your marker position to a screen location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do this, I made a class extending FrameLayout and implementing View.OnTouchListener.  Here's the key part:

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = null;
        for (Point point : points) {
            if(path == null){
                path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
            else {
                path.lineTo(point.x,point.y);
            }
        }

        if(path != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            callback.complete(points,null);
            return true;
        }

        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = event.getX();
        point.y = event.getY();
        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
        //Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);
        return true;
    }
```

`onTouch` captures the touch events, and `invalidate()` triggers `onDraw` which draws the line.  Add one of these to your layout (I did it in Java) and then you can draw on top of the map's markers.